# I am trying to upgrade a bootstrap library from 3.3.7 to 4.6.2 in dojo framework but getting an error when I run the project

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am trying to upgrade a bootstrap library from 3.3.7 to 4.6.2 in dojo framework but getting an error when I run the project as shown in in this image

popper.js error

[image]

If I include popper.js file in the project I get the error as shown here

multipleDefine error

[image]

how to resolve this?

I have replaced bootstrap 4.6.2 files under JavaScript library and added popper.js file externally.

Expectation - to resolve the error I am getting at the moment not able to understand the root cause.